# How to make Jest snapshoots contain style

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Is there a way to create a jest snapshoot which has the css as inline style. For example:

I have a css file with this:

```
.header {font-size: 20px;}
```

**My snapshoot is created like this:**

```
    <div
      className="header"
    >
      some text
    </div>
```

**Is there a way to make the snapshot like this:**

```
    <div
      className="header" style="font-size: 20px;"
    >
      some text
    </div>
```

Than if changing the fontsize in the css file would make the test fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to do this with snapshots, as they only convert the structure of your react component, without knowing anything about what `className="header"` means. For the snapshot this is just property with a string as value.